# Public Key (Assembly a like) extraction from pfx file

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, pfx

I have a problem with extraction of public key from PFX file. First thing which i have used is X509Certificate2. However public key received in this way is encrypted, and i want to have this key to be compatible with 
[InternalsVisibleTo Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) - In *Examples* section there is an sample of such key. Is there a way to extract this key in compatible form (Compatible to InternalsVisibleTo).

Comment: Are you trying to verify Authenticode signature or what? If you need to verify authenticode, then the procedure of such verification is different from comparing public keys. It involves (a) checking signature, and (b) validating certificate.

Comment: Hi Eugene. I am trying to obtain public key, because i need to write automatic process of adding InternalsVisibleTo attribute to AssemblyInfo file. Unfortunatelly i need to consider scenario when i do not have assembly produced by *.proj, but i have a pfx which signs this assembly (And with help i want to extract this public key).

Comment: The assembly can be signed using a keypair (.NET signing using sn.exe) and using Authenticode (in this case a PFX file can be involved). What you are looking for is .NET signing yet it doesn't involve PFX. So there's some confusion about the process here.

Comment: I know that assembly can be signed with snk (keypair). There is no problem with obtaining public key from such file. However i need to use pfx file. It can be loaded for example with X509Certificate2. Here problem starts for me. Public key in X509Certificate2 is in form - "modulus and exponent". Is there a way to obtain Public Key in assembly public key form (Without using sn.exe, just with .NET BCL)? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Not sure about what you are referring as public key in assembly? Can you some more information in your post. May be some screen shots of your X509Certificate2 based public key and public key in assembly. On the other-hand, if it just extracting of public key from the PFX, then it is straightforward process, which i can assist you with.

Comment: I have clarify my question. Straight extraction of PublicKey from X509Certificate2 is not an option in here i think (But maybe i am wrong). Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: @MichaelMocko using a PFX to sign an assembly results in a **completely different signature** that is **never used by InternalsVisibleTo** (you can, and often do, have both a strong name 'snk' signature and authenticode `pfx` signature) - so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *simply* a formatting issue, i.e. X509Certificate2 should return you the decrypted public key (or fail, e.g. bad password).

I suggest you to follow what Mono does to strong name assemblies, i.e. its own [**sn**](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/sn.cs) tool. While Mono's sn.exe does not directly read PKCS#12 files it can read from key containers, so you end up with a **RSACryptoServiceProvider** in both case.

Just drill down into the [source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/sn.cs) code, it's all C# and not very long, and you'll find what you need there (or in one of the few helper classes that are involved).

Comment: That's it. Public Key from X509Certificate2 needs to be transformed to be acceptable by InternalsVisibleTo. Digging through sn.exe (From mono) and than through source of [StrongName](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security/StrongName.cs) and [CryptoConvert](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/CryptoConvert.cs) helped in my case. Thank you a lot.